# Constructing an irreducible representation that doesn't map an element to identity

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

I'm studying off an old qualifying exam, and one of the questions is as follows: If $G$ is a finite group, and $\{ \phi_{i} \}_{i \in I}$ are the irreducible representations of $G$ (I presume over some fixed field, say, $\mathbb{C}$, though the question as written doesn't specify), then $\bigcap_{i} \ker(\phi_i) = \{ e\}$. It gives the hint to consider the regular representation of $G$. The way I read this is "if $h \in G \setminus \{e\}$, then there exists an irreducible representation $\phi : G \to \mathbf{GL}(V)$ of $G$ such that $\phi(h) \neq \operatorname{id}_{V}$". The trouble here is that I don't know how to construct such a representation in such generality. I can generally construct a $\mathbb{C}$-subspace of $\mathbb{C}[G]$ such that $h$ fixes the vector space and isn't the identity, e.g. $W = \operatorname{span}_{\mathbb{C}} \left\{ \sum_{k = 0}^{|h| - 1} e^{2 \pi i k / |h|} h \right\}$, but in general this isn't a $G$-invariant subspace.

I don't know where to go with this one, and would appreciate any advice. Thanks!

Comment: Possible hint. Do you know how to decompose the regular representation into irreducibles? Perhaps see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1805843/why-all-irreducible-representations-appear-in-the-regular-representation .

Comment: I know the regular representation decomposes into all $r$ irreducible representations, and the dimensions satisfy $\sum_{k = 1}^{r} d_i^2 = |G|$. I don't know how to work with that, unless there some counting-type argument I can use.

Comment: If something were in the kernel of every irreducible then it would be in the kernel of the regular representation. (Seems simple. Maybe I am missing something. It's been a long time since I thought about this part of mathematics.) This is the newly posted answer.

Comment: They really ought to have specified that the characteristic of the field does not divide $|G|$, because the result is false without that assumption.

Comment: @DerekHolt Well I suppose the result is true if it's taken to include all irreducible representations over every field, but I agree that the wording is poor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that we are working over a field $K$ with $\operatorname{char}(K) \nmid |G|$, so that $K[G]$ decomposes into irreducible representations by Maschke’s Theorem.

An element $g \in G$ is contained in $\bigcap_{i \in I} \ker(\phi_i)$ if and only if it acts trivially on every irreducible representation of $G$.
Since $K[G]$ decomposes into irreducible representations it then follows that $g$ acts trivially on $K[G]$.
But then $g = g \cdot 1_{K[G]} = 1_{K[G]} = 1_G$.

Comment: Well boy do I feel silly now.